# Google extensions: intercepting a site script and calling function in my content script

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, intercept

I want to call site functions from this script: https://vk.com/js/al/page.js?3042739337 or get event in my content script when some function called in this site function.

How can intercept the moment of connection site scripts and also call it isnide my code?

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: @noogui hello, for example, i want to call site function "Wall.showEditReply('id', event)" from this script site: https://vk.com/js/al/page.js?3042739337 in my content script, in the moment, when user's pressing alt button. Sorry for my english, hope you understand me ^^

Comment: @noogui any solution?